# JSON Data in a Grid using Onsen-UI framework

Tags: json, angularjs, onsen-ui

I tried to get the JSON data and populate it in a grid but found out that OnsenUI uses ons-col and ons-row and no tag for grid. so i used a tutorial example [Link here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_json) and edited as given below, thought it would work, but as a newbie i was wrong

(snippet 1)

```
<ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;" ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat="x in names">
<ons-col align="center">
{{x.Name}}
</ons-col>
<ons-col align="center">
{{x.Country}}
</ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

(snippet 2)

```
<script>
 module.controller('myController', myController);
 function myController($scope,$http) {
      $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
      .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
 }
</script>
```

What i really need is to display the name in one column and country in another. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code works fine. I tried running it and it displays names and countries in two columns.

Comment: I'm getting a blank screen. [Screenshot](http://varanjith.com/images/image_repo/Untitled.png)

Comment: Is your ajax call actually returning any response ??

Comment: Yes, when using it in a list, it displays the name and country, 
    <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div ng-controller="myController"> 
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
     {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </ons-row>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the function after registering the controller, so you're passing a undefined value to `controller()`.

```
module.controller('myController', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
      .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
});
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/xbOjwB

Comment: You did it again @Andreas-Argelius, Thank you. It works. one simple mistake learned.